# Where can I change the automatic lock screen preference?

Tags: lock-screen

I'm using ubuntu in a VM, so, I leave it idle from time to time. When I go back obviously the screen is locked, but I would like to configure the idle time for something around 10 minutes. Where can I do this?

Comment: This question depends on what window manager you are running. Are you using Gnome, KDE, XFce, ...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open up the screensaver preferences: *System ➜ Preferences ➜Screensaver*.

You will see a slider to set the idle time:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the screen from being locked when the computer wakes up from suspend or hibernation, do the following:

> open gconf-editor
>
> navigate to: apps > gnome-power-manager > lock
>
> disable the appropriate flags.

This worked like a treat for me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:
System > Preferences > Power Management

System > Preferences > Screen Saver

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the screen from being locked when the computer wakes up from suspend or hibernation, do the following:

- open `gconf-editor`
- navigate to: *apps > gnome-power-manager > lock*
- disable the appropriate flags.

I know this is not related to running Ubuntu in a virtual machine, but it might be useful for others nonetheless.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work