# Execute a shell-script when closing laptop lid

Tags: 12.04, laptop, scripts

Now I have two scripts and I want to execute them respectively when I close the laptop lip and open it. 
How can I do this?

Comment: The answer by Rafael in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64570/how-do-i-configure-the-screen-to-lock-when-i-close-the-lid/68483#68483) might give you some ideas.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopLidAndDockScripts  explains it.

Comment: What is the action when your laptop lid is closed: hibernate, suspend or do nothing?

Comment: Did you find a way already? I try to do something similar: [Disable touchscreen on closing laptop lid](http://askubuntu.com/q/525878). So if you know a way please answer your own question here

Comment: @Rinzwind: this is last updated in 2012 and it seems really complicated

Comment: Considering that the lid closure dims the light and finally dims to zero...polling for the brightness value in the backlight folder in etc directory can help run a script at laptop lid closing..

Comment: Laptop Lid close is noticed by the Power Management system, which, happily enough, has hooks for additional user actions built in. This will get you started:  `less /usr/share/doc/pm-utils/*`

Answer (score 2):

Use acpi:

The event is handled by acpi:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/acpi/handler.sh
```

I did something like this:

```
    button/lid)
        case "$3" in
            close)
                logger 'LID closed'
        USER=$(ps -C i3 -o user=)
        if test $USER; then DISPLAY=:0.0 su $USER -c "/usr/bin/i3lock -i /usr/share/pixmaps/Screensaver.png"; fi
                ;;
```

Automatically starts i3lock when i close my lid.